# In Java - how do I get a full stack trace

Tags: java, java.util.logging, printstacktrace

Currently I get the following output from code run

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:227)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:256)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.endElement(HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.java:560)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.endElement(HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.java:514)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1192)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1132)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:219)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:312)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3189)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2114)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:937)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:443)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:394)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.parse(HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.java:760)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoHtmlParser.parseFragment(HtmlUnitNekoHtmlParser.java:158)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoHtmlParser.parseFragment(HtmlUnitNekoHtmlParser.java:112)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Element.parseHtmlSnippet(Element.java:868)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Element.setInnerHTML(Element.java:920)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLElement.setInnerHTML(HTMLElement.java:676)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:188)
    ... 30 more
```

The above `... 30 more` means that I do not know the line of my code that causes the problem. How can I get the full stack trace.

Also, if it does not seem to be running any of my catch statements with `printStackTrace`, but if I turn off logging with the below command

```java
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);


**Have put in my full code below as suggested by the comments below . Did not put in the actual URL though**

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;
import java.io.File;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;



public class download_to_send_to_stackoverflow
{
     public static void main(String args[])
     {

      String url = "did not want to include the actual web site ";


      HtmlPage page = null;

      WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
      webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);  
      webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  // tried making false - but didnt work
      webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
      webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
          webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(30000);
      webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(30000); //e.g. 50s
      webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(15000) ;   // added 2017/1/24
      webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(30000) ;   // added 2017/1/24


          try
               {
               page = webClient.getPage( url );
           savePage_just_html(page );  
           }

          catch( Exception e )
               {
               System.out.println( "Exception thrown:----------------------------------------" + e.getMessage() );
               e.printStackTrace();
               }
     }




     protected static String savePage_just_html(HtmlPage page)
     {
          try
          {
            File saveFolder = new File("spool/_");
            page.save(saveFolder);   // this is the line causing the error with limit stack trace
          }



          catch ( Exception e )
          {
               System.out.println( "IOException was thrown: ---------------------------------- " + e.getMessage() );
               e.printStackTrace();
          }


          return "file.html";
     }



}



------------------------------------------------------


  page.save(saveFolder);   above is the problem line.  if I take it out I dont get the limited statcktrace errors but I also dont save the html page - which I want to do

- The question is - why does this line only print a limited stacktrace
```

Answer (score 2):

The "Caused by" means that this is a nested exception.

The "... 30 more" in a nested exception stacktrace means that those 30 lines are the same as in the primary exception.

So just look at the primary stacktrace to see those stack frames.

---

Apparently your exception stacktraces are being generated in a way that is suppressing (or removing) the primary exception stacktrace.  This is puzzling, but it is probably being done by one of the unit testing libraries that you are using.

Getting to the bottom of this will probably involve you either debugging whatever it is that is generating the stacktrace, or writing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that someone else can debug it.

Comment: Thank-you very much for your answer.

Comment: But , the stack trace is not coming from any of my catch's and e.printStackTrace. It only seems to come when I include the 2 lines : -

Comment: java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

Comment: But these 2 lines seem to be  only printing half the stacktrace - I would love to add code so that the full stack trace is being printed.

Comment: Have edited the original question to add the code - as suggested by the above answer